# (Express Validator) req.check doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser, express-validator

I use Express Validator for a update form.
But when I run my function, I have this error.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I check all my code and i think a little response with POST

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "location": "params",
            "param": "password",
            "msg": "password is required"
        },
        {
            "location": "body",
            "param": "confirmPassword",
            "msg": "password and passwordConfirm are not equals",
            "value": "amazingPassword"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't understand why the location on password is in "params" ??
All my variables are in location body, but password and confirmPassword are in location params.

I don't know if i'm clear. Express Validator is ok, the problem is the crash of node who have sent a response to the client.

My app use body parser, a duplicate of var password, it is possible ?

**My POSTMAN configuration:**
[image: My POSTMAN configuration]

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You postman screenshot saying that you are not sending password.

Comment: Yes, Thank but it's just for showing the error message and the location : params  :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using this:

```
const { check } = require('express-validator/check');
```

And this function check everything: body, cookies, headers, params, query. According to your screenshot you are not sending password, so check doesn't know where it should be.

If you are expecting password in body, use

```
const {body, query, param} = require('express-validator/check');
body('password').exists()
```

Second error simply says that you already sent headers(validation errors) and trying to do it one more time(maybe sending some error in catch, dunno, share your controller code)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I use this code.

var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(bodyParser()); 

 req.check('password', 'password is required').notEmpty(req.body.password);
    req.check('confirmPassword', 'confirmPassword is required').notEmpty(req.body.confirmPassword);
    req.check('confirmPassword', 'password and passwordConfirm are not equals').equals(req.body.password);